# Email Contact Form

Tags: forms

I have and email form on my website with some jQuery validation in place. What is the best way to plug this form into EE to email me output leaving the jQuery validation in place?

There is front end code (jQuery) performing some validation on my form, that is checking for an actual email address or spam etc... When I use EE's build in form module it seems to ignore this front end validation so anything can go into the form and it submits OK. I need a solution that retains this front end validation within my form before it has been submitted?

Any help would be appreciated.

Hi here is my front end code does this help at all?

```
 <p>
                                          <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                                          <input type="text" name="message[]" id="name" class="required">
                                        </p>

                                        <p>
                                          <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                                          <input type="text" name="message[]" id="email" class="required email">
                                        </p>

                                        <p>
                                          <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                          <input type="text" name="message[]" id="subject" class="required">
                                        </p>

                                        <p>
                                          <label for="message">Your Message</label>
                                          <textarea name="message[]" id="message" class="required"></textarea>
                                        </p>

                                        <input type="hidden" name="from" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="" />

                                        <p>
                                          <input type="submit" value="Send it">
                                          <img class="ajax-loader" src="/_/images/bckg/loader_light.gif" alt="Sending ...">
                                        </p>
```

Comment: Please add more detail of exactly what your trying to accomplish. Are you looking for a Forms module? Are you trying to control the markup of the form?

Comment: What jQuery library are you using? What does your jQuery code look like? Can you post a sample of your EE template code too? Are there any errors in the error console?

Comment: Almost of your inputs have the same name!? Why? This is the only thing that looks like wrong and this has nothing to do with EECMS.

Comment: Thanks where can I find out how to set up the EE form correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressionEngine has a built-in [email module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/email/contact_form.html) for just this purpose. It's pretty limited though, but it will accomplish what you need.

If you want something a bit more flexible, try Solspace's [Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/). There are both free and commercial versions available.

I think between the options I've mentioned you should find a good fit for your application. As with any EE module, they're not going to mess with your front-end, so your work on validation with jQuery should be safe.